# Browser Extension: Window click event not fired when registering at 'document_start'

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, mouseevent, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have created an extension, which will automatically inject content script at 'document_start'. I register 'click' event when injecting, but on some pages, the event does not work.

manifest.json:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Test",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Test extension",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "https://*/*",
                "http://*/*"
            ],
            "js": [
                "content_script.js"
            ],
            "all_frames": true,
            "run_at": "document_start",
            "match_about_blank": true
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "tabs",
        "webNavigation"
    ],
    "host_permissions": [
        "https://*/*",
        "http://*/*"
    ]
}
```

content_script.js:

```
console.log('create global mouse handler');

window.addEventListener(
    'click',
    (e) => {
        console.log('click!');
    },
    true,
);

'1';
```

For every pages, the line 'create global mouse handler' will be printed.
For most of the pages, the line 'click!' will be printed when I click on the page.
For some pages, the line 'click!' will not be printed when I click on the page.

Example working page: stackoverflow pages.
Example not working page: [Google translate extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-translate/aapbdbdomjkkjkaonfhkkikfgjllcleb)

Do you know the reason why?

P.S. I also test injecting content script at 'document_idle', but the problem still exists for chrome webstore page.

Comment: Extensions can't work on webstore pages in Chrome. Your code works for me on StackOverflow.

Comment: Hi wOxxOm, yes it is the problem I'm facing with, and I cannot figure out why it does not work in some pages, like Chrome webstore.

Comment: If I register a click handler via DevTool, the event will work as expected, so it is not that Chrome webstore page prevents the event.

Comment: Ah, did you mean that Chrome itself restricts extension action on the webstore pages? If that is the case, the first line 'create global mouse handler' should not be written so that we can understand the situation.

Comment: The line is printed by the content script running in a youtube video embedded there.